# Is this the right way to use "at" closure in Geb

Tags: java, groovy, spock, geb

Scenario: I have a login page which uses ajax to validate a user and if invalid login, it stays on the same page.

I am wondering if this is the correct way to use the **at** in Geb or I can improvise on this. Concerns:

1. I am using waitFor with hard-coded timeout etc.
2. Should waitFor be in **at** block?
3. Is there a better way of writing this?

**Spec def**

```
def "perform invald login"()
{
    given: "I am at the login page"
    to LoginPage

    when : "I entered invalid data"
    loginForm.loginClientCode = "test"
    loginForm.loginSystemCode = "test"
    loginForm.loginUserId = "test"
    loginForm.loginPassword = "test"

    loginButton().click()

    then: "Log in attempt unsuccessful"
    at(LoginPage)
}
```

**Page object**

```
class LoginPage extends Page
{
    static url = "login/login.jsf";

    static at =
    {
        waitFor(10,0.5)
        {  $("div.ic-h1").text() == "User Authentication" }
    }

    static content =
    {
        loginForm
        {
            $("form",id: "loginForm")
        }

        loginButton
        {
            $("button", id: "loginButton")
        }

        statusMessages
        {
            $('div.ui-messages').text()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually keep the at only for the purpose of verification and then do:

```
waitFor{ at LoginPage }
```

But this might not be needed given the new support for implicit assertions in 0.7. http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/implicit-assertions.html#at_verification

I think what you really want here is to test for the existence of an error message and waitFor that.

i.e,

```
 loginButton().click()

 then: "Log in attempt unsuccessful"
 waitFor{ statusMessage == 'this login failed' }
```

since you can't really get your then condition to fail otherwise.

Moreover, you could probably put the condition into a state of your page object, so something like

```
def isErrorState() {
    statusMessage == 'this login failed'
}
```

and in your test, it becomes easier to read.

```
waitFor{ isErrorState() }
```

Comment: +1 can you elaborate on what exactly is not needed due to the support of implicit assertions

Comment: sorry, what I meant is that you would normally do a waitFor{ at LoginPage } and then test for at LoginPage. But now with geb 0.7. you can just do a waitFor{ at LoginPage } and not do an additional check